# Como usar vários App.config

Tags: c#, .net, app.config

Como utilizar mais de um App.Config? Tenho uma Solution com vários projetos. Em cada projeto há um App.Config. Quando tento realizar a leitura de uma chave, seja pelo `AppSettingsReader` ou pelo `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` a chave é procurada no App.Config do projeto Startup e não no projeto de onde está sendo feita a chamada.

Comment: E tá certo, este é o comportamento esperado.

Comment: Se um projeto é compartilhado entre diversas soluções, este projeto não pode ter um arquivo próprio de configuração?

Comment: Pode, estou postando uma ideia pra você

Comment: Pode, o @LINQ está postando uma ideia p/ você.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é o comportamento esperado.

Você pode ter arquivos de configuração separados, mas terá que fazer a leitura manualmente, os dois métodos citados por você irão capturar as informações do arquivo de configuração do *assembly* que está sendo executado.

Você pode usar o método [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx) pra capturar um objeto do tipo `Configuration` e buscar os dados salvos no `appSettings` dele.

Algo como:

```
public string GetAppSetting(Configuration config, string chave)
{
    var element = config.AppSettings.Settings[chave];
    return element?.Value ?? "";
}
```

O uso seria assim

```
string configLocal = this.GetType().Assembly.Location;
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configLocal);

string myValue = GetAppSetting(config, "chave");
```